# What is cookie reverse engineering?

Tags: penetration-test, cookies, reverse-engineering

I want to know what is this cookie reverse engineering and how to do this is simple words. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not fancy. You look at some cookies from the website and try to figure out what information they encode, then try to change the values returned and see if it does anything useful to you. At one extreme, a cookie value like `UserToken=f7a7731073f766c6f555a0b9a821dded` is unlikely to be any use to you. But if you have cookies like `Item=iPhone6&Price=899` it's worth changing them to `Item=iPhone6&Price=99` and seeing if you can pick up a bargain. Or if your cookies say `UserName=foo&Password=bar` then if you can get access to someone else's cookies you can probably get into their account.

Comment: So you mean tampering a cookie and changing the parameters is called cookie reverse engineering?